# Updating forks on Bitbucket/Git

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am working with 2 friends in a project.

There is a Main Project which I did a Fork(main fork), then my other 2 friends create a Fork of my Fork (haha sorry I felt stupid explaining this), now I just update my Fork with some code, how my friends can update their Forks with the new updates I did on mine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You push your changes from your local copy to your forked-repo.  Your friends add your original fork as a remote to their local repos.  They pull from you, and push to *their* forks.  Here are the specifics for your friends:

```
git remote add nietzsche <url-to-your-fork>
git fetch nietzsche
# do stuff
git push origin <refs>
```

Where `do stuff` is checkout branches from nietzsche and/or merge to master or other branches.  For instance:

```
git checkout master
git merge nietzsche/master
# resolve any conflicts
git push origin master
```

Comment: In my local Fork I just did a push, so my Fork has updates. They want to update their Forks with my updates. How they do the remote thing?